# Having trouble setting up AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

So I was trying to setup something really basic, but can't figure out for the hell of me why angularjs is not displaying the stuff inside the curly brackets. I'm utterly stumped

link to the plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/GfCgemAxZPkhKNv7A0Av?p=preview

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.27" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.27/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainstyle.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="maincontroller.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="maincontroller">
      <p>{{introduction}}</p>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

script.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myProgram',[]);
```

maincontroller.js

```
app.controller('maincontroller', maincontroller);

var maincontroller = function($scope) {
  $scope.introduction = "Welcome to My Program";
}
```

Comment: Are there still any problems with angular? If your problem was solved by an answer, you should accept it like [described  here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If not, please edit your question or comment on the answers.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 errors that you could see if you take a look at your js console of your browser.
I updated your [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vD4RewmvTp7q8mRJxPPa?p=preview).

**404 & angular undefined**

The link to angular was simply wrong.

**Cannot read property `controller` of undefined**

In your maincontroller.js you tried to add a controller before you defined the function. A better approach taken from the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller):

```
app.controller('maincontroller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.introduction = "Welcome to My Program";
}]);
```

**Argument `maincontroller` is not a function**

This time the console even gives you a [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=maincontroller&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined) with a description of the problem. The cause is, that you forgot to set the `ng-app` attribute to your app:

```
ng-app="myProgram"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues.

You forgot to reference your main module in the html:

```
<html ng-app="myProgram">
```

You have a broken link to angular.js. Use the CDN link as provided on the [angular site](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/downloading).

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
```

You assign maincontroller before it is defined. One way to fix this is by simply not assigning it to a variable first:

```
app.controller('maincontroller', function($scope) {
  $scope.introduction = "Welcome to My Program";
});
```

A more general tip: check out this [seed project](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) for a best practice on how to organize angular apps.

Comment: Adding the angular lib, I mean. Is there something I'm missing or am I flat-out stupid?

Comment: It looks like this link is simply broken: https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.27/angular.js

Comment: Welp, that's unfortunate. Alright. Thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: @HamzaIbad I edited my answer to address all the issues.